# binary search cant find the correct key

Tags: java, binary

ok, so I coded a program in java that reads the values from a file and stores them in an array and then pass them to binary class where the binary code will search for the key. Now if the key is listed in the file it will show the location and the key but if the key is not listed it will output the key is not listed. 
my program works fine if my key is say 6474 or i believe until index reaches 500 but once the key is located (7988) it shows the key is not listed even though the key is in the file. Any help would be appreciated.....

p.s. i have 667 values in my file and my key is 7988. no, it does not throws any error.

here's the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MyMain {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int key = 8681;
    int num;
    int phySize = 5000;
    int logSize = 0;
    int[] anArray = new int[phySize];

    File myFile = new File("integers");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(myFile);

    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        num = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(" logSize " + num);
        anArray[logSize] = num;
        logSize = logSize + 1;
    }

    // System.out.println(" The log size is " + logSize);

    BinSearch Bin = new BinSearch();
    SeqSearch Seq = new SeqSearch();



    int count = -1;

    while (count < logSize) {
        count++;
        if (anArray[count] == key) {
            break;
        }
    }

    int j = Bin.BinarySearch(anArray, logSize, key);
    int k = Seq.sequentialSearch(anArray, logSize, key);
    //System.out.println(" The number of count is " + count);

    // System.out.println(" The logical Size is " + logSize);

     }
   }
```

binary search class:

```
 public class BinSearch implements IBinarySearch {

 public int BinarySearch(int[] anArray, int logSize, int key) {

    int firstNum = 0;
    int lastNum = (anArray.length - 1);
    int middleNum = (firstNum + lastNum) / 2;

    while (firstNum <= lastNum) {
        if (anArray[middleNum] < key)
            firstNum = middleNum + 1;
        else if (anArray[middleNum] == key) {
            System.out.println(key + " found at location "
                    + (middleNum + 1) + ".");
            break;
        } else
            lastNum = middleNum - 1;

        middleNum = (firstNum + lastNum) / 2;

    }

    if (firstNum > lastNum){
        System.out.println(key + " is not present in the list.\n");
    }
    return key;
   }

  }
```

output 1:

```
 logSize 5134
 logSize 5743
 5134 found at location 329.
```

second output with a larger key:

```
logSize 9974
logSize 9990
9990 is not present in the list.
```

Comment: Downvoting. You can refer how to ask a question by checking http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and how to create an example by reading this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I don't see any problems with my question? what all the down votes???

Comment: Because you are just dumping code, no stack-trace and expect people to go through it and try to understand. Read both the links I gave.

Comment: It states what the problem is and i have no clue why? if I would I wouldn't be asking the question???

Comment: there's no stack trace because I don't know where or which line is causing the problem.... like i stated, the program runs fine and there's no errors. once it reaches a certain point it just shows the key is not listed.

Comment: Doesn't work this way my friend. Read the links I gave. Secondly, You should reduce the problematic code, try to isolate the issue. This helps people also understand, and to be honest, the explanation you are giving in first para, you are writing what you are thinking, we dont have the context information which you have, confusing the users more.

Comment: i worked on this code for 12+ hrs and still couldnt figure out where my problem is. there doesn't seem to be any problem from what i understand. and yes i did read your links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your output only prints two `logSize` messages, I conclude that `logSize = 2` and `anArray.length = 5000`, so you probably meant:

```
int lastNum = (logSize - 1);
```

Why else pass `logSize` in?

Given that, you claim that `5134 found at location 329` is impossible. Location 329 will be a `0`.

Comment: Dude, you're f**king Awesome!!!!! Thank YOU so much. that's all i needed and it fixed the problem. (logSize - 1) was all i needed.

Comment: Can someone please up vote his solution for me. since i have less than 15 rep and cant!!!